# Create Feature running into timeout error

Tags: features

When clicking on Create Feature I get an timeout with the message

> Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\sites\all\modules\contrib\features_override\features_override.export.inc on line 382

When I disable the Feature Overrides Module it works again. Turning it on again I get the same error.
Any hints on how to find the real problem behind this?

Comment: http://xdebug.org/ ?

Comment: at the moment it looks like features override is just way to slow for working with it